# Youtube homepage doesn't work

Tags: epiphany

Youtube.com isn't working properly. I can watch embedded videos normally, but if I go to the homepage or try to watch a video on youtube, this is all that shows up. Tried turning off the adblocker with no results.

[image: Only the top bar appears.]

I've looked around and I haven't seen this issue anywhere. Anyone have any idea what's going on?

EDIT: I signed out of Google and it turns out youtube.com works while signed out. 
But this created another problem. I don't know if it's related to the new Google login design but after I put my password in, the next page is just blank and it doesn't log me in.

Answer (score 4):

This should already be fixed now, but for the record, this was a YouTube bug that was triggered by a WebKit user agent quirk designed to make the old YouTube website work better. See https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=171603.